# Find all possible Jordan Canonical forms for a nilpotent linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

Find all the possible Jordan forms for $T$
$$T:V \rightarrow V$$
$$\dim(V) = 6$$
$$T^3 \not= 0$$
$$T^4 = 0$$ 
My solution is that the JCF matrix would be of size $6 \times 6$, the first block would be of size $4$ and the rest is either two blocks of size $1$ or one block of size $2$.

Am I correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, you are. Just don't forget to mention that the diagonal entries are all $0$, though! :)

Comment: Yes it seems correct. Also the eigenvalue coupled with the 4x4 block would need to be 0 of course.